# результат запроса USSD

Tags: android, ussd

Добрый день.
Пытаюсь разобраться как получить результат ussd запроса, нашел несколько вариантов
Один через Accessibility, но как пишет автор метод работает только при активном экране. Второй вариант это парсинг logCat дикий костыль и работает далеко не везде.
У меня же запрос вызывается периодически из сервиса, и там же должен обрабатываться. Получается что оба варианта мне не подходят.
Можете подсказать в какую сторону копать?

Comment: кто-то вирусы пишет ...

Comment: Нет :) хочу написать приложение для анализа оставшихся минут гигабайт на семейном пакете билайна. Чтобы можно статистику посмотреть и тд.